# Prevent HTML code from being stolen

Tags: html, psd

I am showing a demo of PSD to HTML to my client. I want to upload the HTML document with CSS files and images in my server to show the demo to the client.

I am afraid if he will copy the HTML code.

Is there any way to decode / encode the html code so that it will not be understandable to copy?

Even if i prevent Right Click on the page he can use View > Page Source option or can save the webpage and then see the source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Source Code Stealing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590483/prevent-source-code-stealing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot protect your JS, CSS or HTML code 100%.

But you could confuse your client by encrypting the code, removing whitespaces, etc. He could copy and paste it but will not be able to edit or extend it that easy.

This tool encrypts HTML to JS:
http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter

CSS compressor (removes whitespaces and new lines):
https://csscompressor.net/

JavaScript compressor (removes whitespaces and new lines): http://javascriptcompressor.com/

As @AMR already mentioned: protect your copyright and setup a contract. My advices above are just in case, if there is no trust in your client!

Comment: But in the browser developer tools it is trivial to get the HTML for the DOM after the JS has run.

Comment: @MartinSmith of course, it's just an advice. it depends on the project and the clients know-how.

Comment: my answer was marked as the right one, but I got a few downvotes. kinda weird.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of stopping it. You can do what @Mr.Bombastic said but I would just suggest writing a quick nondisclosure form and have the person sign it. You can also just put comments in your page that show its yours. In the end if they steal it and its your code it should be pretty easy to prove even without comments. Civil lawsuits aren't that much.