# Angularjs and Firebase: avoid code stolen?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am pretty new to javascript and Angular...
Firebase + Angular are great toghether.
But without a back-end I am really afraid that all my web-app could be easily copied?

Is it correct? If so, there is a guidelines to avoid it?

Thank you

Comment: Since 90% of your code is boilerplate and commonplace, what you need to secure are the revolutionary, amazingly proprietary components (i.e. the algorithm that calculates those stellar, unbelievably perfect matches for you dating app). Move that code to a server where you can protect it. Don't concern yourself with anything else--it's not worth stealing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent your html, css, js code from being 'Stolen' all you can do is try to make it hard to do.

Copywriting and Legality
The more code you write the easier it will be to prove your the author so if your code is stolen you can sue.

Tips to Make your Code More You
Following industry best practices on writing good code will help you keep a consistent style, that in the end kind of proves your the author.

Obfuscation
You should obfuscate your code enough to make it difficult enough to copy. Those that will try to deobfuscate your code will likely do it as a hacking exercise. The amount of effort required to hack your code could just be put into creating Apps. As far as how much code is stolen in the real world, I think a lot of people do it just for learning.

This topic has been discussed on this site a lot. See below articles.

[How to prevent your JavaScript code from being stolen, copied, and viewed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660060/how-to-prevent-your-javascript-code-from-being-stolen-copied-and-viewed)

[Prevent HTML Source Code Stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590483/prevent-html-source-code-stealing)

[Prevent HTML code from being stolen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507601/prevent-html-code-from-being-stolen)

Comment: Thankyou, already seen it. Probably Angularjs + Firebase can be easily copied.